# Bind bool 'object not null' to Enabled property in control in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

I have a bool variable, CanSave, and an object called Selected. Sometimes Selected is null so I need some textboxes to disable when this happens. This is my code:

```
    private MyObject _selected;
    public MyObject Selected
    {
        get { return _selected; }
        set { 
            if (_selected != value) 
            { 
                _selected = value;
                CanSave = Selected != null;
                OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
            } 
        }
    }

    private bool canSave;
    public bool CanSave
    {
        get { return canSave; }
        set { if (canSave != value)
        {
            canSave = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CanSave");
        } }
    }
```

I tried many things, I'm even binding to a Label and the label does respond to the property change.

```
        txt_descripcion.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", this, "CanSave")); //this doesn't work
        label8.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this, "CanSave")); //this works
```

Any guide would be awesome, thanks in advance!

Comment: It should work. Try this `Selected = Selected == null ? new MyObject() : null;`

Comment: What is the class those properties belong to?

Comment: I am assuming this code belongs to a Form or UserControl which implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Try posting all the relevant code. With the information you've provided, there's no way to tell why it isn't working. (I posted your code into a form, added the two controls, implemented OnPropertyChanged and the PropertyChanged event, and it worked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Igby Largeman said, I read the relevant code and thinking about how he actually made it work, and found somewhere in the code where I clear all bindings in the control. I haven't work in this code for weeks, so I forgot that happened, thanks Igby.